# Pass a variable in as a member name to an Object?

Tags: vb.net, variables, object, member

Not sure if this is even possible but I need to be able to pass a variable's value in as an object's member name.

Basically I'm using a wdsl that has a number of objects where some of them could contain a collection, I need to make data grids to show the data in the collection which is straightforward enough but at the moment I have to make code for each object/collection that defines how many effective columns and their names and types.

This works fine albeit a bit long winded but it will also break if the wdsl changes and the objects collection content changes (names, types etc.)

What I need is to be able to pass a object name to a sub which will work out if the object contains a collection (PropertyType will contain []), read its name and pass that name down to a loop which will go through at the correct level to retrieve the "column" names and data types.

I have got almost all of this working until I want to pass the collection name into a loop as an object member name as it obviously doesn't evaluate the string value of CollName in the below example, it will just error saying CollName isn't a member of the object which of course it isn't but the variables actual value would be.

```
    Sub IterateObject(objName)
    Dim CollName = ""
    For Each m As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In objName.GetType().GetProperties()
        If m.CanRead Then
            If InStr(m.PropertyType.ToString, "[]") <> 0 Then
                CollName = m.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next
    For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In objName.CollName(2).GetType().GetProperties()
        If p.CanRead Then
            If p.Name <> "ExtensionData" Then
                MsgBox(p.Name & " - " & (p.PropertyType.ToString))
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way of doing effectively `objName.(value of CollName)(2).GetType().GetProperties()`

Comment: I dont quite follow and suspect an XY issue, but a collection name is usually of little value, the Type *in* the collection tends to be more interesting. Configuring for a Type based on an empty collection can be done, but you need to start with the object (not collection name) and the collection needs to be a Generic.  An arraylist of the grody VB Collection wont tell you anything about the Item Type

Comment: I probably haven't explained very well so I'll try to give an example. I have an method from the wdsl that will return an object of a type something like  "SrvRef.RetrieveActiveSupplyChainsResponse", in object browser I can drill down to "ActiveSupplyChains" which shows as {Length=11} much like an Array, this contains field names and values and in this instance has 11 results in it that I need to display in a grid.

Comment: Having now established the array/collection name ("ActiveSupplyChains") I now need to loop through "ActiveSupplyChains" to get the field names and field types within. The above code works fine if it explicitly define the member name so objName.ActiveSupplyChains(2).GetType().GetProperties() works but only where the collection name is "ActiveSupplyChain". I need to be able to extract this (which the first reflection loop achieves and pass it into the second loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have fixed it using CallByName to allow me to make a new object out of just the bit I need

```
Sub IterateObject(objName)
    Dim CollName = ""

    For Each m As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In objName.GetType().GetProperties()
        If m.CanRead Then
            If InStr(m.PropertyType.ToString, "[]") <> 0 Then
                CollName = m.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Dim CollObj
    CollObj = CallByName(objName, CollName, CallType.Get)
    For Each p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo In CollObj(0).GetType().GetProperties()
        If p.CanRead Then
            If p.Name <> "ExtensionData" Then
                MsgBox(p.Name & " - " & (p.PropertyType.ToString))
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```